# Microsoft Fakes - make stub with auto implemented sub-objects

Tags: c#, .net, stub, microsoft-fakes

I Wonder, is there any way to make stub of interface that automatic implement all properties of this interface, especial when they are non-base types. 
Example:

```
public interface TopInterface
{
    int Counter { get; set; }
    SubLevel1Interface ChildObject { get; set; }
    SubLevel1Interface OtherChildObject { get; set; }
}

public interface SubLevel1Interface
{
    string SomeText { get; set; }
    SubLevel2Interface SomeObject { get; set; }
}

public interface SubLevel2Interface
{
    DateTime dateOfMotezumaBirthday { get; set; }
}
```

And when im stubbing TopInterface class, default behavior of all not-stubed properties is to throw null. And for my test purpose, these properties cannot be null. This causes that i'm forced to write big amount of trivial code, like:

```
StubTopInterface someStub = new StubTopInterface
{
    CounterGet = () => 15,
    ChildObjectGet  = () => new StubSubLevel1Interface
    {
        SomeTextGet = () => string.Empty,
        SomeObjectGet = () => new StubSubLevel2Interface(),
    },
    OtherChildObjectGet = () =>  new StubSubLevel1Interface
    {
        SomeTextGet = () => "FooBaal",
        SomeObjectGet = () => new StubSubLevel2Interface(),
    },
};
```

When property that Counter - other object just cannot be null. So I would be so happy if there be some way to write some like:

```
StubTopInterface someStub = new StubTopInterface
{
   CounterGet = () => 15,
}
```

And rest of object would auto-stubbed itself. 
Is there way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a way to automatically stub things built in. You might possibly be able to use reflection to provide values, but it'd be very complicated. More likely, your problem is that your classes rely too much on eachother, but that may just be the way it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default behaviour you have to write the code. There is no way to auto generate this beyond what is available.

The right way to save on code rewrite is to refactor this out to a common location like say your class/test initialize and then override behavior per test case.